# Lucene TextField not compatible with TermQuery?

Tags: java, lucene, tokenize

I am currently indexing my text values to the document with TextField, for example

```
document.add(new TextField(name, value, Field.Store.YES))
```

When I am searching for those values, I use a TermQuery that has one Term inside, that corresponds to the name and value previously set in document.

Executing my TermQuery is not returning any results when my text is added with TextField. If I use StringField, it is working.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: `TextField` is analyzed. `StringField` is not. If you want to search for the entire content of the field as an identifier or something, StringField is the correct choice. If you want to search for words in a text, use TextField.

Comment: yes, but Im I supposed to search in a TextField with TermQuery? If not, which query should I use?

Comment: Sure, you can use TermQuery to search in a TextField, to match one term within that field.